# Django Template - Bootstrap table numbers in accounting format

Tags: javascript, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Django templates for populating following bootstrap table in UI. I want numbers in the table to be more readable (by using ',' between digits) - for example: if a number is one million, then it should be shown as 1,000,000 and not 1000000 (notice commas ',' between digits).

[image]

Code

```
<tr id="port_row_{{row.stock}}_{{index}}">
    {% if row.stock == 'TOTAL'%}
        <td> {{row.stock}}</td>
    {% else %}
        <td> <a target="_blank" style="color:blue;" href="https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE:{{ row.stock }}">{{row.stock}}</a></td>
    {% endif %}
    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
    <td>{{row.monday_open_price}}</td>

    <td>{{row.previous_close}}</td>
    <td>
    {% if row.price >= row.previous_close %}
        <div style="color:green">
        {{row.price}}
        </div>

        {% else %}
        <div style="color:red">
        {{row.price}}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    </td>

    <td>{{row.investment_amount}}</td>

    <td>
        {% if row.weekly_gain >= 0 %}
        <div style="color:green">
            +{{row.weekly_gain}}
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
        </div>

        {% else %}
        <div style="color:tomato">
            {{row.weekly_gain}}
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </td>
    <td>
        {% if row.daily_gain >= 0 %}
        <div style="color:green">
            +{{row.daily_gain}}
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
        </div>

        {% else %}
        <div style="color:tomato">
            {{row.daily_gain}}
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `django.contrib.humanize` when rendering your price.

> A set of Django template filters useful for adding a “human touch” to data.
>
> To activate these filters, add 'django.contrib.humanize' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting. Once you’ve done that, use {% load humanize %} in a template, and you’ll have access to the following filters.

[Document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/)

in your code, do
`<td>{{ row.monday_open_price|intcomma }}</td>`

Do not forget to `{% load humanize %}`